# Icecast streaming from web

Tags: flash, apache-flex, icecast

I need to stream audio to an icecast server from my web site. Which is the best solution for make this application? I think I can use Flex / Flash to streaming audio but I can't find any solution. Basically I need to develop a conference web application.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Icecast client for flash:
http://code.google.com/p/anoggplayer/